# Liquibase generateChangeLog MissingObjectChangeGenerator

Tags: java, liquibase

I'm using Liquibase and trying to use the command liquibase generateChangeLog.
I'm using the correct connector and credentials. The debug trace shows this error at the end, after catching infos from all tables.

```
DEBUG 14/09/17 16.30: liquibase: MissingObjectChangeGenerator type order:     liquibase.structure.core.Catalog    liquibase.structure.core.Schema    liquibase.structure.core.Sequence    liquibase.structure.core.StoredProcedure    liquibase.structure.core.Table    liquibase.structure.core.Column    liquibase.structure.core.PrimaryKey    liquibase.structure.core.UniqueConstraint    liquibase.structure.core.Index    liquibase.structure.core.ForeignKey    liquibase.structure.core.View
Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

SEVERE 14/09/17 16.30: liquibase: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:265)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1011)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:188)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:103)
Caused by: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:13)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:263)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
        at liquibase.change.ColumnConfig.<init>(ColumnConfig.java:119)
        at liquibase.change.AddColumnConfig.<init>(AddColumnConfig.java:16)
        at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.core.MissingIndexChangeGenerator.fixMissing(MissingIndexChangeGenerator.java:63)
        at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.ChangeGeneratorChain.fixMissing(ChangeGeneratorChain.java:47)
        at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.ChangeGeneratorFactory.fixMissing(ChangeGeneratorFactory.java:99)
        at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog.generateChangeSets(DiffToChangeLog.java:193)
        at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog.print(DiffToChangeLog.java:147)
        at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog.print(DiffToChangeLog.java:88)
        at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog.print(DiffToChangeLog.java:75)
        at liquibase.command.GenerateChangeLogCommand.run(GenerateChangeLogCommand.java:54)
        at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:8)
        ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I finally found the solution.

There were these problems:

1. Columns with names separated by spaces.
2. Tables without primary keys.
3. Indexes over primary keys.

So, eliminating spaces, giving PKs and removing useless Indexes the error disappeared and I could go on.

Thanks anyway.